# Rupture field of an irreducible polynomial over a finite field equals its splitting field

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

> Let $k= \mathbb{F}_{q}$ a finite field and $P \in k[X]$ an irreducible polynomial. Show that its rupture field is also its splitting field.

My take :

Let $K$ be the splitting field of P. By the primitive element theorem, $K= k(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in K$. If I show that $\alpha$ is a root of $P$, then it is finished. But is it a root of $P$ ?

Comment: What is a rupture field? And no, $\alpha$ need not be a root of $P$.

Comment: @Servaes I mean by rupture field a field extension of $k$ generated by a root of $P$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have never heard it called that before.

Comment: The question is handled as a part of  [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/409681/11619). I would expect there to be a better match. And won't use my dupehammer to point at a question I answered myself.

Comment: Another [related oldie](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2486386/11619).

Comment: I want to also mention [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38197/11619).

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/790741/11619) also works, assuming that you know the basic properties of normal extensions.

Comment: [The same thing happens, when we know that the Galois group is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1778337/11619). The haul is a bit disappointin :-(